# Is there an API/Library that will return the Authentication Level of an Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

I'm currently writing an android app where I use PackageManager to get all of the installed applications on the device. I want to order them in a recyclerView based on their level of authentication (if they require a fingerprint, passcode, or facial recognition to use). Is there any library or API out there that can get me close to something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any library or API out there that can get me close to something like this?

No. You can use `PackageManager` to see what apps request the `USE_FINGERPRINT` or `USE_BIOMETRICS` permissions. However:

- You have no idea to what extent the app is using those permissions
- That may not cover device-specific proprietary SDKs (e.g., Samsung's)
- You have no way of determining if an app requires a password or other forms of authentication